# Compiling Cheese from source, fails to compile

Tags: command-line, compiling, webcam, cheese, autotools

I am trying to install cheese from source, and Im not interested in finding a package, because I have source code changes I should like to apply, if I can get it to compile. I have libtool automake, and autotools-dev installed.
When I try to run `./autogen.sh` I get this error:

```
     ./autogen.sh 
**Warning**: I am going to run `configure' with no arguments.
If you wish to pass any to it, please specify them on the
`./autogen.sh' command line.

+ gtkdocize --copy
+ intltoolize --force --copy --automake
+ autoreconf --verbose --force --install -Wno-portability
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force --warnings=no-portability -I m4 ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}
configure.ac:189: error: macro YELP_HELP_INIT is not defined; is a m4 file missing?
m4/ax_require_defined.m4:35: AX_REQUIRE_DEFINED is expanded from...
configure.ac:189: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
+ exit 1
```

I have looked on the GNOME wiki, github page, and in the source for a description on compiling, and for similar errors on Google but I have not found a solution yet. Please note, I am simply trying to compile the Un-modified source prior to applying my changes.

UPDATE:
I installed some additional packages, not because they were clearly listed as dependencies, but because I read about it on an Arch forum.

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf gtk-doc-tools yelp-tools appstream-util libx11-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev libgnome-desktop-3-dev libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev libclutter-gst-3.0-dev libcanberra-gtk3-dev valac
```

It now compiles, but the compiled program only works in the source folder. The installed binary throws this error when Cheese is called:

```
$ cheese
cheese: error while loading shared libraries: libcheese.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am running Ubuntu Mate 15.10.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but the `yelp.m4` file  is provided by [package yelp-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/all/yelp-tools/filelist)

Comment: did you perform a `make install`? the system cannot find the libcheese.so.8 either because the LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not include system library paths or because the make install hasn't copied the library to the system library path, or because you chose a different install location for the cheese app. also running ldd cheese should show what libaries it expects and if it can find them. please supply that if you are still having problems

Comment: yes, I did sudo make install, but libcheese.so.8 fails.  maybe I need to dig around in the make files for where libcheese.so.8 is exported.  libcheese.so.7 is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese.so.7` on a non-source install

Answer (score 0):

Use `apt-get build-dep cheese` to install all the dependencies.